# Proper way to flush database in MVC 4 test application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In the past I've deleted the `.mdf` file found in `App_Data` but that's caused problems for me. So what's the proper way to completely flush the database?

Comment: Deleting it through the "SQL Server Object Explorer" in VS 2012 rather than the Solution Explorer seems to have worked.

Comment: @AmirHosseinMehrvarzi: Yes, using code-first EF.